# PyQt5 add QListWidgets to QGridLayout via ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, pyqt5, threadpoolexecutor, qlistwidget, qgridlayout

I am trying make a PyQt5 GUI that allows:

1. Launch of a UI file selector on button click, filters for .csv files.
2. If a file is selected, load the file into a pandas data frame.
3. For each data frame column, access the unique elements of that data frame column and create a QListWidget containing the unique values of that column.
4. Each QListWidget is added into a QGridLayout that is also a scrollable area.

So far, I have been able to do just that. When attempt to scale up the functionality to .csv files containing ~1M rows, as one could expect there is a performance hit. To get around the slow down I am attempting to instantiate QListWidget objects that are added into a QGridLayout via a concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor. Using the ThreadPoolExecutor, I get no errors and none of the debug prints indicate that anything is unexpectedly.

In the method DataManager::load_data there is a call to DataManager::make_data_filters which works just fine. However, switching the call to DataManager::make_data_filters2 or DataManager::make_data_filters3 results in a much faster response but no QListWidgets are added/visible inside the QGridLayout.

I presume for testing that any standard/tabular .csv file will work, that is the intent after all. My main goal is to speed things up for large .csv files. Any comments, suggestions, fixes, or alternative approaches are welcomed, thanks. The code below contains everything that you need, except for a standard tabular .csv file. For my own sake, I just downloaded some dummy data from the internet.

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class ixListBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):    

    def __init__(self, label_str, values, callback_selection, *args, **kwargs):
        
        # Call the parent constructor
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Track the selection callback
        self.callback_selection = callback_selection
        
        # Initialize the widget layout
        self.init_widget_layout()         
        
        # Initialize the dtaa filter space
        self.init_label_space( label_str=label_str )      
        
        # Initialize the button space
        self.init_listbox_space( values=values )
        
        
    def init_widget_layout(self):       
        
        # Create a layout manager for the central frame/widget
        self.central_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        # Connect the layout to the frame
        self.setLayout( self.central_layout )


    def init_label_space(self, label_str):

        # Initialize a label
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label.setText( label_str )
        label.setAlignment( QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter ) 
        
        # Add label to widget
        self.central_layout.addWidget( label )
        
        
    def init_listbox_space(self, values):

        # Initialize a listbox
        self.listbox = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        
        # Set widget to allow multiselection
        self.listbox.setSelectionMode( QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection )
        
        # Connect the listbox to a selection callback
        self.listbox.currentItemChanged.connect( self.callback_selection )
            
        # Add the values to the listbox
        self.listbox.addItems( values )
        
        # Add listbox to widget
        self.central_layout.addWidget( self.listbox )
        
        
class DataManager(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

    def __init__(self, label='Data Manager', *args, **kwargs):
        
        # Call the parent constructor
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Set the title bar
        self.setWindowTitle( label )
        
        # Initialize widget default values
        self.init_widget_values()
        
        # Configure widget properties
        self.init_widget_properties() 
        
        # Initialize the widget layout
        self.init_widget_layout()
        
        
    def init_widget_values(self):
        
        # Variable to track widget visibility
        self.is_visible = True
      
      
    def init_widget_properties(self):
        
        # Set whether the widget is initially docked
        self.setFloating( False )
        
        # Connect the dock to a visibility callback
        self.setVisible( self.is_visible )
        
        # Set the allowed area that can be docked into
        self.setAllowedAreas( QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea )
        
        # Set the enabled features of the widget
        self.setFeatures( QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable | QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable )
    
    
    def init_widget_layout(self):       
        
        # Create a central frame
        self.central_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        
        # Create a layout manager for the central frame/widget
        self.central_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        # Connect the layout to the frame
        self.central_frame.setLayout( self.central_layout )
        
        # Connect the layout manager to the central frame
        self.setWidget( self.central_frame )        
        
        # Initialize the dtaa filter space
        self.init_data_filter_space()      
        
        # Initialize the button space
        self.init_button_space()
        
        
    def init_data_filter_space(self): 
        
        # Initialize a scrollable area
        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable( True )
        scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget( scrollAreaWidgetContents )
        
        # Create a layout manager for the central frame/widget
        self.layout_filters = QtWidgets.QGridLayout( scrollAreaWidgetContents )
        
        # Add the button space frame to the layout
        self.central_layout.addWidget( scrollArea )
        
        
    def init_button_space(self):        
        
        # Create a central frame
        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        
        # Create a layout manager for the central frame/widget
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        
        # Connect the layout manager to the central frame
        frame.setLayout( layout )
        
        # Add the button space frame to the layout
        self.central_layout.addWidget( frame )
        
        # Initialize a load data button
        self.make_button( layout=layout, label='Load Data', callback=self.load_data )
        
        # Initialize a save data button
        self.make_button( layout=layout, label='Save Data', callback=self.save_data )
        
        
    def make_button(self, layout, label, callback):        
        
        # Initialize a button
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setText( label )
        button.clicked.connect( callback )
        
        # Add the button to the layout
        layout.addWidget( button )
        
        
    def load_data(self):        
        
        # Set the UI properties
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseCustomDirectoryIcons
        
        # Launch a file selection UI
        file_name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName( self, 'Load Data File', os.getcwd(), 'Excel files (*.csv)' )
        
        # Check if a selection was made
        if not file_name:
            return
        
        # Load the data into a data frame
        self.df = pd.read_csv( file_name )
        
        # Load and make data filters based on file contents
        self.make_data_filters3()
        
        
    def save_data(self):        
        
        print('SAVE DATA')
        
        
    def make_data_filters(self):
        
        # Get the data column keys
        row_indx = col_indx = 0
        for column_key in self.df.columns:
            
            # Get the unique values for the current column
            values = self.df[ column_key ].astype( str ).unique().tolist()
            
            # Initialize a list box to track the unique values
            listbox = ixListBox( label_str=column_key, values=values, callback_selection=self.callback_filter_selection )
            
            # Add the listbox widget to the layout
            self.layout_filters.addWidget( listbox, row_indx, col_indx, 1, 1 )
            col_indx += 1
            
            # Check for new row condition
            if col_indx > 4:
                row_indx += 1
                col_indx = 0
                
                
    def make_data_filters2(self):        
                
        # Build the listbox instances in parallel    
        with ThreadPoolExecutor( os.cpu_count() - 1 ) as executor:
            listboxes = executor.map( self.get_listbox_filter, [ column_key for column_key in self.df.columns ] )
                
        # Get the data column keys
        row_indx = col_indx = 0
        for listbox in listboxes:
            
            # Add the listbox widget to the layout
            self.layout_filters.addWidget( listbox, row_indx, col_indx, 1, 1 )
            col_indx += 1
            
            # Check for new row condition
            if col_indx > 4:
                row_indx += 1
                col_indx = 0
                
            print(listbox, row_indx, col_indx)
            
            
    def make_data_filters3(self):

        # Pre-calculate the listbox positions
        row_indx = col_indx = 0
        widget_positions = []
        for column_key in self.df.columns:
            
            # Track the widget position
            widget_positions.append( ( row_indx, col_indx ) )
            
            # Increment the column count
            col_indx += 1
            
            # Check for new row condition
            if col_indx > 4:
                row_indx += 1
                col_indx = 0
                
        # Build the listbox instances in parallel    
        with ThreadPoolExecutor( os.cpu_count() - 1 ) as executor:
            executor.map( self.get_listbox_filter2, [ widget_spec 
                                                      for widget_spec in zip( self.df.columns, widget_positions ) ] )
    
   
    def get_listbox_filter(self, column_key):
        
        # Get the unique values for the current column
        values = self.df[ column_key ].astype( str ).unique().tolist()
        
        # Initialize a list box to track the unique values
        return ixListBox( label_str=column_key, values=values, callback_selection=self.callback_filter_selection )


    def get_listbox_filter2(self, widget_spec):
        
        # Extract the inputs
        column_key = widget_spec[ 0 ]
        row_indx, col_indx = widget_spec[ 1 ]
        
        # Get the unique values for the current column
        values = self.df[ column_key ].astype( str ).unique().tolist()
        
        # Initialize a list box to track the unique values
        listbox = ixListBox( label_str=column_key, values=values, callback_selection=self.callback_filter_selection )
        
        # Add the listbox widget to the layout
        self.layout_filters.addWidget( listbox, row_indx, col_indx, 1, 1 ) 
        
        print(listbox, row_indx, col_indx)
        
        
    def callback_filter_selection(self):
        
        print('callback_filter_selection')        
        
        
    def toggle_visibility(self):
        
        # Toggle the visibility state
        self.is_visible = not self.is_visible
        self.setVisible( self.is_visible )    
        

class RootWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        # Call the parent constructor
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # Initialize the application layout
        self.init_app_layout()
        
        # Initialize the application widgets
        self.init_app_widgets()
        
        
    def init_app_layout(self):
        
        # Create a central frame
        self.central_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        
        # Create a layout manager for the central frame/widget
        self.central_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        # Connect the layout manager to the central frame
        self.central_frame.setLayout( self.central_layout )
        
        
    def init_app_widgets(self):
        
        # Initialize a DataManager instance
        self.data_manager = DataManager( label='Data Manager' )
        
        # Add the data manager to the application
        self.addDockWidget( QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.data_manager )
        
        # Connect the dock widget to a key press callback        
        self.shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut( QtGui.QKeySequence( 'Ctrl+D' ), self )
        self.shortcut.activated.connect( self.data_manager.toggle_visibility )
        
        
    def finalize_window(self):
        
        # Set the central widget of the application
        self.setCentralWidget( self.central_frame )


def main(): 
    
    # Check for an existing Qt app instance
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication( sys.argv )
        
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

    # Create a widget instance
    main_app = RootWin()
    
    # Show the application
    main_app.show()
    
    # Run the main event loop of the application
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Call the main routine
    main()
```

Comment: You cannot (and should not) create or modify the GUI from another thread as the GUI is not thread-safe. Maybe in your IDE the error messages are not visible but I recommend you run the script from the console and you will get: *QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread* *QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread*.

Comment: First thing, I ran the code from a conda prompt and sure enough a bunch of QBasicTimer outputs. Did some digging on the bone you threw and was able to declare a pyqtSignal in the DataManager class and use the ThreadPoolExecutor to emit the input(s) I need for making a listbox and adding it into my gridlayout. Much thanks to you good Sir! Till next time, take care. End result is ability to add millions of rows to more than one listbox widget at a time in a reasonable amount of time.